# DNN Label HelpText is below my menu

Tags: label, dotnetnuke

I have a few DNN Labels on my page, and ones near the top have their HelpText go underneath my menu (RadMenu). I have been looking around and can't find a way to get the HelpText to show above the menu.

So my question is whether or not I can somehow offset this helptext or make it's zindex higher than the menu's.

I do not just want to make the label's zindex higher than the menu's cause I will run into issues when I use my menu and the label text being above the menu.

[image: HelpText zindex issues]

This is what it currently looks like. I would prefer to have the zindex change rather than offsetting the HelpText box as it has that arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just change the z-index for dnnTooltip to be higher

```
.dnnTooltip {z-index:999;}
```